# how to setup and test if a location is using the closest rds read replica? aws

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, rds

I am currently learning how `rds replica` works in aws.
I got everything setup and now I have a `postgres rds instance` in the origin of `oregon` which is the original `rds instance`.  Then I created one `cross origin read replica` which is in the origin of `tokyo`.  How do I setup and test if people nearby `tokyo` is actually access the `read replica` from `tokyo` instead of accessing the original `rds instance` in `oregon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each RDS Read Replica has a DNS endpoint. You could combine DNS Server Geolocation, such as provided by Route 53, to provide the endpoint closest to the customer's location.

To test and verify this, you would need to enable logging for your RDS instance and then manually map the customer's IP address -> region -> read replica to verify.

Comment: is the dns endpoint something like `xxxxxxxxxx.-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

thx thx for the reply, I think I have an idea but just settings up seems the need of lots set up